# How to include jquery Countdown timer plug-in in Blogger template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, blogger

I am using Blogger and the 'simple' template to create my blog. I want to put in a countdown timer. Through research, I've found that the best way (that allows customisation) is using a JQuery plugin from Keith Wood (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

I'm not sure how to include this in my html code...I've tried many things and I can't get it to show up at all. Here is an extract from my code which is located just before the < / head >:

```
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'/>
<link href='https://www.dropbox.com/s/apli554dvptb01r/jquery.countdown.css'    rel='stylesheet'/>
<style type='text/css'>
body &gt; iframe { display: none; }

#defaultCountdown { width: 240px; height: 45px; }
</style>
<script src='https://www.dropbox.com/s/kt99b0ly3cx8u7l/jquery.plugin.js'/>
<script src='https://www.dropbox.com/s/mr7tsda8236nerh/jquery.countdown.js'/>
```

From my understanding, what I've done is link to the JQuery database (using Google), then link to my own hosting of the plugin that I want to use and the CSS information.

Then in the post (location where I want my timer), I have put the following code in:

```
$(selector).countdown({until: liftoffTime});

var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear}); 

$('#removeCountdown').click(function() { 
var destroy = $(this).text() === 'Remove'; 
$(this).text(destroy ? 'Re-attach' : 'Remove'); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown(destroy ? 'destroy' : {until: newYear}); 
});
</script>
```

From here, my plan was to look at this on my blog, and then make any necessary changes - i.e. the date to which it counts down, the size and the font style.

I have no idea where I'm going wrong....since this produces nothing on my post at all.

Please help! :) Thanks everyone!

Comment: You should always have a glance at the console output of your browser (F12 or look for dev tools). If anything goes wrong it will be printed there.

Comment: Ah ok! Yes there are a few errors:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.plugin.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.countdown.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: selector is not defined (index):736

Answer (score 0):

```
Unexpected token < jquery.countdown.js:1
```

is a common error that should have been a 404 but has been redirected to a html page (and thus returning an invalid **<** character because of `<html>`).

Generally speaking: you're js files can't be loaded correctly, check their path and also check if dropbox allows for hotlinking to these files.

Comment: Ok, I've checked the links and they are correct. From what I can find on the net Dropbox allows hotlinking. Why would it not be working though? Have I correctly included my links in my code?